# Can the gravel used under my pool be used patio stone?

Tags: pool, patio, stone, gravel

We bought our first house recently and have dove head first into renovations and landscaping. One thing that is really bugging us is the state of our back yard. We sold our above-ground pool and destroyed the MASSIVE deck (took up about 60% of the yard) that the previous owners had installed. You can imagine how much sand and dirt is visible...

We are planning to install a much smaller deck and a stone patio next to it. We are trying to keep costs down and are wondering if the gravel used underneath the pool (now gone) is suitable to be used under a stone patio.

I am referring to the technique in this image:
[image]

So the 6" of class V gravel would, in our case, be the gravel from underneath the pool.

The gravel under the pool is kind of a mix of gravel and sort-of-clay. It seems to allow water to pool if it rains really heavily. It seems very solid and almost hardened into a weak concrete. I have to whack it quite hard with a spade to get it to break apart. That is one thing that has me doubting this idea.

If anyone has any experience with this i appreciate the guidance!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my honest opinion if the idea of it turning into a soft concrete is what gave your fear, do not let it. That is the point of having a gravel base and the sand is simply there to easily level the pavers. Save money and recycle. :)

The gravel is used as saving money if you will from not having to pour a slab. Which also allows for a homeowner to do these types of projects. Many times in on jobs where there is concrete we just add sand and pave right over it, if it is uneven. If smooth you can add pavers and fill with sand.

Comment: Im happy to hear from someone with experience! Thank you for the reply. I'll save the gravel then :)

Comment: Cheers, my pleasure. Would like to see a pic after your project is done. :)

Comment: So it's all finished and I have to say it is solid as a rock (no pun intended). Also, it drains just fine. Even with the hose, I can't get a puddle to form. Thanks again for the advice!